Naturality of an isomorphism for hypercohomology
Let $X$ be a topological space and $\mathcal{F}^\bullet$ be a complex, concentrated in non-negative degrees, of acyclic sheaves on $X$ which are valued in the category of abelian groups $\textbf{Ab}$. From the degeneration of one of the two standard spectral sequences converging to hypercohomology at the second page, there is an isomorphism of abelian groups:
$$ \theta_{k,\mathcal{F}^\bullet}: h^k(\Gamma(X, \mathcal{F}^\bullet)) \xrightarrow{\sim}  \mathbb{H}_{\textbf{Ab}}^k(X, \mathcal{F}^\bullet)  $$
where the left hand side is the $k^\text{th}$ cohomology group of the complex of abelian groups obtained by applying the global sections functor $\Gamma: \text{Ch}_{\geq 0}(\textbf{Sh}_{\textbf{Ab}}(X)) \rightarrow \text{Ch}_{\geq 0}(\textbf{Ab})$ to the complex $\mathcal{F}^\bullet$. So that all of my notation is clear, let me clarify that I am writing e.g. $ \text{Ch}_{\geq 0}(\textbf{Sh}_{\textbf{Ab}}(X))$ to denote the category of chain complexes, concentrated in non-negative degrees, valued in the category of abelian sheaves on $X$.
My question is whether these isomorphisms form the components of a natural isomorphism? Specifically, I mean the components of a natural isomorphism $\theta_k$ between the functors:
$$h^k \circ \Gamma: \text{Acy}(X) \rightarrow \textbf{Ab} \text{ and }  \mathbb{H}_{\textbf{Ab}}^k(X, -):  \text{Acy}(X)  \rightarrow \textbf{Ab}, $$
where $\text{Acy}(X)$ is the full subcategory of $ \text{Ch}_{\geq 0}(\textbf{Sh}_{\textbf{Ab}}(X))$ consisting of complexes of acyclic sheaves on $X$. I suspect that this is true, and is most likely a specific instance of a more general result about the degeneration of (cohomological) spectral sequences but I cannot prove it myself. If anybody could point me towards a reference that treats the isomorphisms $\theta_{k, \mathcal{F}^\bullet}$ categorically, I would be very grateful.
Thanks,
Tom.

The isomorphism comes from a degeneration of a spectral sequence, so it suffices to observe that the spectral sequence is natural. This is the case, essentially by carefully staring at your preferred construction of that spectral sequence.

Thanks for your comment, Thorgott :) What do you mean here when you say the spectral sequence is natural? I've had a look for the definition in McLeary's book on spectral sequences and, while he does mention the naturality of certain spectral sequences in chapter five, he doesn't seem to give a definition (I may have just missed it).

There is a notion of a morphism of spectral sequences, which is given by morphisms between the bigraded objects on every page that are compatible with the respective differentials. You mention McCleary's book as a reference, so I point you to p.65 there for more. These morphisms now define a category $\mathbf{SpecSeq}$ of spectral sequences. The punchline is that the hypercohomology spectral sequence in fact comes in the form of a functor $\mathrm{Ch}_{\ge0}(\mathbf{Sh}(X))\rightarrow\mathbf{SpecSeq}$. The compatibility with morphisms is precisely what is meant by the 'naturality of the hypercohomology spectral sequence'. The isomorphisms in your question are obtained from the data of the spectral sequence by virtue of degeneration, so you then get for free that these are natural.
Unfortunately, I don't know of a reference off-hand that makes this naturality really explicit. Instead, I recommend you look at a construction of the spectral sequence (e.g. in Weibel's An Introduction to Homological Algebra, Chapter 5.7) and convince yourself at every step along the way that it's compatible with the induced morphisms.

Thank you Thorgott :) This is a really helpful answer!
